# while es lo mismo que for en rendimiento? python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucle-for, script, while

bueno estaba haciendo un projecto con un amigo que no sabia usar el "for"
entonces para que algo pase X veces el hacia

```
i = 0
while i != 10:
 print(i)
```

(i no siempre es la variable que usamos)

pero cuando vi el codigo que hizo habian como 5 while entonces le conte como se usa el for

pero el for en python hace un cambio "que se note en rendimiento" al cambiar todo esos whiles?
o dejo todos los while de mi codigo ahi

Comment: Depende de para qué quieras usar el ciclo, el **while está pensado para cuando el número de iteraciones no es conocido inicialmente**, o al menos el número máximo de iteraciones no es conocido, en este caso un for no sirve. Por otro lado usar un while para iterar sobre una lista u otro iterable es una idea pésima, un for trabaja sobre iteradores y es mucho más eficiente y legible en este caso. Si vas a generar números del 0 al 9,un for con range sigue siendo mejor idea que el while.

Comment: tiene sentido ponlo como respuesta y le dare tilde

Comment: @FJSevilla El tiempo que necesita el `print` es mucho más largo que el `for` o el `while`. Si tiemop de ejecución es importante, hay que pensar en numpy, o numba, o compilar con PyC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Son dos ciclos que funciona de forma distinta:

- Un ciclo `for` itera sobre sobre una colección, iterable o generador. En cada iteración toma un item del objeto y lo asigna a la variable o variables asociadas al mismo.
- El ciclo `while` simplemente itera hasta que la expresión de control es evaluada como `False`.

Por norma general un ciclo `for` es más eficiente que un ciclo `while`. El ciclo `while` necesita comprobar en cada iteración que la condición de control sea evaluada como cierta o no para salir.

El ciclo `while` está pensado principalmente para aquellos casos en los que el número de iteraciones no es conocido de antemano, más específicamente, cuando el número máximo de iteraciones no es conocido antes de iterar. El ciclo `for` en cambio está pensado para iterar sobre cualquier objeto iterable.

Hay casos en los que el ciclo `while` es imprescindible, uno muy típico es cuando se valida la entrada de usuario y no queremos terminar hasta que éste ingresa algo válido. De antemano no sabemos si el usuario ingresará algo válido a la primera o necesitará 1000 intentos...

```
while True:
    inp = input("Ingrese un entero: ")
    try:
        n = int(inp)
    except ValueError:
        print("No ha ingresado un entero válido. Vuelva a intentarlo.")
    else:
        break
```

Luego hay casos en los que jamás debemos usar un `while`, por ejemplo para iterar sobre cualquier objeto iterable sin más, sin necesitar reasignar un nuevo objeto a un item:

```
lista = [1, 2, 5, 7, 13]

lenght = len(lista)
i = 0
while i < lenght:
    n = lista[i]
    i += 1
```

> %%timeit 486 ns ± 5.51 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

Además de menos legible, es mucho más ineficiente que usar un `for`:

```
for n in lista:
    pass
```

> %%timeit 88.9 ns ± 6.93 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

parece una tontería pero yo he visto cosas como esta, principalmente en gente que viene de otros lenguajes e intenta traducir código sin más.

Incluso cuando queremos iterar `n` veces, es mejor usar un `for  + range` que un `while`:

```
for i in range(100):
    pass
```

> %%timeit 1.33 µs ± 41.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

---

```
i = 0
while i != 100:
    i += 1
```

> %%timeit 3.87 µs ± 82.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Por norma general:

- Usa un `for` para todo lo que puedas, si se tiene cualquier contenedor, iterador, generador o rango y queremos recorrerlo un `for` es lo adecuado, en cualquiera de sus variantes:

  ```
  # Solo iterar y obtener los elementos
  for item in lista:
      print(n)

  # Asignar nuevo objeto a los índices
  for i in range(len(lista)):
      lista[i] += 1

  # Obtener el item y asignar nuevo objeto a los índices
  for i, n in enumerate(lista)):
      print(n)
      lista[i] + = 1
  ```
- Para todo lo demás, si no se conocen el número máximo de iteraciones a realizar, no tenemos un contenedor o generador que procesar o no vamos a iterar sobre un rango concreto debemos usar un `while`.